# Library/UserControl to view and edit .NET Object

Tags: library, c#, .net, user-interface

My company develops an application, which loads different modules at runtime. Each module has a WPF dashboard with a model and viewmodel. My team has a UI test application, which shows the status dashboard of one or multiple modules. The test application is used by software developer, testers and is planned to be used by marketing as well.

For this application I am searching a UserControl, which supports the following features:

- The UserControl shows the current state of the Model. There are many models already created. Therefore the control should be dynamically created at runtime.
- Properties of the model which are complex types are shown with all of its properties and could be changed the same way.
- Properties of the model which are simple Types can be changed through a Textbox.
- Properties of the model which are enums could be changed through a ComboBox. The user see the possible values of the enum and can set it through the ComboBox.
- It would be nice to replace an object of one type with an object of another type. This might require some manual tweaking for each module.
- It's prefered when the library uses WPF. Other frameworks are still ok.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Essential PropertyGrid for WPF](https://www.syncfusion.com/products/wpf/property-grid) supports displaying and editing properties of data objects through built-in editors.

[image: Syncfusion WPF PropertyGrid]

- The UserControl shows the current state of the Model: Yes
- Properties of the model which are complex types are shown with all of its properties and could be changed the same way: Yes
- Properties of the model which are simple Types can be changed through a Textbox: Yes
- Properties of the model which are enums could be changed through a ComboBox. The user see the possible values of the enum and can set it through the ComboBox: Yes.
- It would be nice to replace an object of one type with an object of another type. This might require some manual tweaking for each module: We have prepared an [example](https://help.syncfusion.com/wpf/propertygrid/customeditor-support) to allow user to pick an object instead of editing using CustomEditor Support.
- It's preferred when the library uses WPF: Yes.

The entire product is available for free with no limitations through the [community license](http://www.syncfusion.com/products/communitylicense) if you qualify (less than 1 million USD in annual revenue).

Note: I work for Syncfusion